# Geometry of generalized Lipschitz functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, geometry, lipschitz-functions

Clearly, that geometry of Lipschitz function is a double cone whose vertex can be translated along the graph, so that the graph always remains entirely outside the cone ([image from wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC5kA.png)).

I've found the definition of *generalized Lipschitz functions*:

> Function f is said to be generalized Lipschitz if there exist L > 0 such that |f(x)-f(y)| ≤ L(1+|x-y|), ∀x,y

But a'm really stuck - what is the geometry of 2D *generalized Lipschitz functions*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x$ fixed
$$
-f(x)-L(1+|x-y|)\le f(y)\le f(x)+L(1+|x-y|),\quad \forall y.
$$
[image]